# Issues with setting up child routes in Angular2

Tags: angular, components, router

While trying to organize the whole structure, so I can dive into the actual business logic, I ran into following issue.

I have the main controller with it's routes defined:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'priz-app',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, SecureRouterOutlet, AppHeader],
  providers: [AuthenticationService]
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '/logout', name: 'Logout', component: LogoutComponent },
    { path: '/rrm/...', name: 'Rrm', component: RrmMainComponent }
])
```

and the template of that controller is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <app-header></app-header>
            <secure-outlet signin="Login" unauthorized="AccessDenied"></secure-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there is `app-header` directive included that looks as follows:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './app-header.component.html',
    directives: [Collapse, DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, TrackScrollDirective]
})
```

And somewhere inside it's template:

```
<a [routerLink]="['RrmMain']">RRM <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

where RrmMainComponent looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'rrm-main',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './rrm-main.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, SecureRouterOutlet]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'RrmMain', component: RrmMainComponent, useAsDefault: true, data: { roles:['ROLE_RRM_USER', 'ROLE_RRM_USER'] }}
])
```

All good, but I am getting an exception:

> EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Router! (RouterLink ->
>   Router). angular2.js:23887 EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of
>   Router! (RouterLink -> Router). angular2.js:23877:9
>
> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Child routes are not allowed for "/". Use "..." on
>   the parent's route path.

I tried anything I could think about, but I am stuck at this point. Simply still don't have enough experience with it.

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Did you add `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` in `bootstrap()`? Did you add `<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/router.dev.js"></script>`? Can you create a Plunker to reproduce?

Comment: Yes, I absolutely did. It all working if I have single level routes. As for plunker, I'll do my best, It's quite lasrge code already.

Comment: Please don't add all your code to the Plunker, Only as much as necessary to reproduce the problem (minimal reproducible example). The more code you add, the less likely it is anybody will try to debug the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Günter Zöchbauer.

Thank you for pushing me to create plunker. Because that made me realize what the problem was.

Apparently, in the parent in root route config as well as the child one, I was referencing the same component. 
Once I created a wrapping component like that:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'rrm',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './rrm.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, SecureRouterOutlet]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'RrmMain', component: RrmMainComponent, useAsDefault: true, data: { roles:['ROLE_RRM_USER', 'ROLE_RRM_USER'] }}
])
```

*Note, that here I am linking another component, not itself.*

And referenced it from the app component:

```
{ path: '/rrm/...', name: 'Rrm', component: RrmComponent }
```

Everything worked like a charm !!!

Thanks,

Comment: what is this `SecureRouterOutlet` in the directives list ?

Comment: It's an override of RouterOutlet and it deals with authorization based on routes: https://gist.github.com/ShurikAg/3c8afc05765cf1b5941b3cc3f81523df

Comment: @PardeepJain it is an extension of `route-outlet` class. Generally it is done to put some custom logic globally like `authorization` before you get to the `next or previous route`.